# How to suppress groups in Crystal Viewer programatically in Delphi

Tags: delphi, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report (.RPT File) which has been created by a POS system, I need to get all the records from this report into a database so I can use it in my program. The problem is that it is grouped and have headers and footers, when exporting jut like this it exports a lot of nonsense to the ODBD database. I would like to suppress all Groups and headers and only export the details. In crystal designer I can do this by clicking on each group and suppressing them. I need to do this from within Delphi. See my working code for viewing the data, and currently exporting everything to Excel.

```
`unit Unit2;

interface

uses
Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, 
System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.OleServer,
CrystalActiveXReportViewerLib14_TLB, Vcl.OleCtrls, OleAuto,
CrystalReportViewerExportLib_TLB;

type
 TForm2 = class(TForm)
 CrystalRpt: TCrystalActiveXReportViewer;
 Button1: TButton;
 Button2: TButton;
 CrystalExport: TCrystalReportExport;
 Button3: TButton;
 procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
 procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
private
 { Private declarations }
public
 { Public declarations }
end;

var
Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
oApp : variant ;

begin

  oApp := CreateOleObject('CrystalRuntime.Application')  ;
  crystalrpt.ReportSource :=  oApp.OpenReport('c:\guess.rpt',1);
  {crystalrpt.ShowGroup('Group Header #1') ;}
  crystalrpt.ViewReport ;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 cry : TCrystalActiveXReportViewer;
 oRpt, oApp : variant;
 i : integer;
begin

//Export the report to a file
oApp := CreateOleObject('CrystalRuntime.Application');
oRpt := oApp.OpenReport('c:\guess.rpt',1);
oRpt.ExportOptions.FormatType := 29;  //excel 8
oRpt.ExportOptions.DiskFileName := 'c:\output.xls';
oRpt.ExportOptions.DestinationType := 1;  //file destination
oRpt.ExportOptions.
//Export(False) => do NOT prompt.
//Export(True) will give runtime prompts for export options.
oRpt.Export(false);
end;

end.`
```

Comment: You have the source for the viewer in CrystalActiveXReportViewerLib14_TLB and CrystalReportViewerExportLib_TLB. Does the viewer (`oRpt` in your code) give you any access programmatically over the groups?